# Плавное наведение JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть галерея,при наведении на картинку должен появляться hover с текстом,должно это все выглядеть как  [***ТУТ***](http://www.cubiqdesign.co.uk/)   когда наводишь на картинку он очень плавно появляется затемнение с текстом. Я взяла у них скрипт,изменила в js только классы,но у меня почему-то не работает. Подскажите где я допускаю ошибку. Ниже привела пример кода. Так же можно глянуть [Тут](https://codepen.io/Kulikovka_KyKi/pen/qMEmOo)

```js
/**
        Gets the direction you are moving into ( or out of) an element from.
        0 = top
        1 = right
        2 = bottom
        3 = left
    */
function getDirection($el, coordinates) {

  // the width and height of the current div
  var w = $el.width(),
    h = $el.height(),

    // calculate the x and y to get an angle to the center of the div from that x and y.
    // gets the x value relative to the center of the DIV and "normalize" it
    x = (coordinates.x - $el.offset().left - (w / 2)) * (w > h ? (h / w) : 1),
    y = (coordinates.y - $el.offset().top - (h / 2)) * (h > w ? (w / h) : 1),

    // the angle and the direction from where the mouse came in/went out clockwise (TRBL=0123);
    // first calculate the angle of the point,
    // add 180 deg to get rid of the negative values
    // divide by 90 to get the quadrant
    // add 3 and do a modulo by 4  to shift the quadrants to a proper clockwise TRBL (top/right/bottom/left) **/
    direction = Math.round((((Math.atan2(y, x) * (180 / Math.PI)) + 180) / 90) + 3) % 4;

  return direction;

}

var eventHandler = function() {
  $(this).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $(this).mouseenter(function(event) {

    width = $(this).width();
    height = $(this).height();
    $(this).find('.portfolio-content').css('display', 'block');
    $(this).find('.portfolio-content').css('width', width);
    $(this).find('.portfolio-content').css('height', height);
    direction = getDirection($(this), {
      x: event.pageX,
      y: event.pageY
    })

    switch (direction) {
      case 0:
        $(this).find('.portfolio-content').animate({
          marginTop: "-" + height + "px",
          marginLeft: "0"
        }, 0) /* move into position */
        $(this).find('.portfolio-content').animate({
          marginTop: "0",
          marginLeft: "0"
        }, 200) /* show overlay  */
        break;
      case 1:
        $(this).find('.portfolio-content').animate({
          marginTop: "0",
          marginLeft: width + "px"
        }, 0) /* move into position */
        $(this).find('.portfolio-content').animate({
          marginTop: "0",
          marginLeft: "0"
        }, 200) /* show overlay  */
        break;
      case 2:
        $(this).find('.portfolio-content').animate({
          marginTop: height + "px",
          marginLeft: "0"
        }, 0) /* move into position */
        $(this).find('.portfolio-content').animate({
          marginTop: "0",
          marginLeft: "0"
        }, 200) /* show overlay  */
        break;
      case 3:
        $(this).find('.portfolio-content').animate({
          marginTop: "0",
          marginLeft: "-" + width + "px"
        }, 0) /* move into position */
        $(this).find('.portfolio-content').animate({
          marginTop: "0",
          marginLeft: "0"
        }, 200) /* show overlay  */
        break;
    }
  });

  $(this).mouseleave(function(event) {
    width = $(this).width();
    height = $(this).height();
    $(this).find('.portfolio-content').css('display', 'none');
    $(this).find('.portfolio-content').css('height', 0);
  });
}

function updateGridHover() {
  $('.portfolio-content').animate({
    marginTop: "-1000000px",
    marginLeft: "-1000000px"
  }, 0)

  $('#grid-container .portfoli').each(eventHandler);
}
```

```css
.container-fluid-gallery {
  max-width: 1800px;
  padding: 0;
}

.portfolio {
  position: relative;
}

.portfolio-content {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 18px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: none repeat scroll 0px 0px #6170ca;
}

.portfolio-content_clickable {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<section class="portfolio-area">
  <div class="container-fluid container-fluid-gallery">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="grid-item logo">
        <div class="portfolio">
          <a href=""><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzjGG.jpg" alt=""></a>
          <div class="portfolio-content portfolio-content_clickable">
            <h3 class="portfolio-content-h3">Lorem ipsum</h3>
            <p class="sportfolio-content-p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item grid-item__w2 grid-itemlogo">
        <div class="portfolio">
          <a href=""><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUfno.jpg" alt=""></a>
          <div class="portfolio-content portfolio-content_clickable">
            <h3 class="portfolio-content-h3">Lorem ipsum</h3>
            <p class="sportfolio-content-p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: кстати есть готовое уже, если хотите можете использовать вот это : http://lavalamp.magicmediamuse.com/examples.php

Answer (score 0):

Это проще сделать на CSS. На JS нужно делать если прям точь в точь копировать их подход, конкретно в том что бы понимать откуда на картинку вошла мышь и менять направление анимации. Если это опустить то лучше собрать все на CSS.

```css
.box{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.part{
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.part:hover .shadow{
  display: block;
  animation: left ease 0.5s forwards;
}
.part:hover .desc{
  display: block;
  animation: left ease 0.5s forwards;
}
.desc{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
}
.shadow{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  display: none;
}

@keyframes left{
  from {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }

  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="part">
     <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS9pKhNdORp7GaKjJUTFPfZwZfURmKVFiK5dWKn8eJQM5J40HHlaw" alt=""> 
     <a href="#" class="desc">Мадам</a>
     <p class="shadow"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="part">
    <img src="https://cdn4.techly.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/techly-smartphone-camera-noise-799x423.jpg" alt="">
    <a href="#" class="desc">Хацкер</a>
    <p class="shadow"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="part">
    <img src="https://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/photo/2016/02/smithsonian-magazines-2015-photo-co/s01_GeertWeggen/main_900.jpg?1456418926" alt="">
    <a href="#" class="desc">Мышка в домике</a>
    <p class="shadow"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="part">
    <img src="https://iso.500px.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/stock-photo-114337435-1500x1000.jpg" alt="">
    <a href="#" class="desc">Follow Me</a>
    <p class="shadow"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Похоже,спасибо)Но меня немного смущает, что движение по рядам происходит,то есть если перемещаться по картинкам где-то в центре, все равно будет выезжать слева того ряда на котором стоишь..а можно как-то похожий эффект сделать,но без этого?